# Python, round DOWN time to the nearest 15mins clock mark

Tags: python, ceil

how am i able to round down time to the nearest 15mins clock mark.
the code below rounds to the nearest 15mins clock mark, i.e if time is 5:08 to becomes 5:15. however i would like to make this round down not up and become 5:00
please help

here is my code

```
fajr_jamaat = ceil(fajr_jamaat_date).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

and the function is

```
def ceil(dt):
    if dt.minute % 15 or dt.second:
        return dt + timedelta(minutes = 15 - dt.minute % 15, seconds = -(dt.second % 60))
    else:
        return dt
```

Comment: Just set minutes to math.floor(dr.minutes/15)*15. I wouldn't use timedelta if I were you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work.

```
import datetime

def ceil(dt):
    minut = int(dt.strftime('%M'))*60
    secon = int(dt.strftime('%S'))
    h = int(dt.strftime('%H'))
    tot = minut + secon
    #print(tot)
    nearest = round(tot/900)*900
    #print('time is %d:%d'%(tot/60, tot%60), 'nearest fifteen mark is %d:%d'%(nearest/60, nearest%60))
    if nearest/60 == 60 and h < 23:
        nr_15_mark = dt.replace(hour=h+1, minute=0, second=0)
    elif nearest/60 == 60 and h == 23:
        #wrapping the hour back to 0 
        nr_15_mark = dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
    else:
        nr_15_mark = dt.replace(minute=int(nearest/60), second=nearest%60)
    return nr_15_mark

#fajr_jamaat_date = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1,23,58,0)
fajr_jamaat = ceil(fajr_jamaat_date).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
#print(fajr_jamaat)
```

Please note that as we are considering only hours, minutes and seconds, i'm ignoring the date addition when we are finding the nearest mark when the time of fajr_jamaat_date exceeds 23:47:30.

Comment: I get the following error nr_15_mark = dt.replace(minute=int(nearest/60), second=nearest%60)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Comment: @Ossama that is strange. `int(nearest/60)` should convert it to integer and remainder can't be a float. I have tested with times closest to all the 15 mins mark. Can you tell me what is the time period which you have entered when you got this error?

Comment: time is 05:08:00

Comment: [output](http://imgur.com/a/TI6sc). It's working for me. Can you try printing the input before passing it to the function and remove # from the first two print statements, run it and take a screenshot and post it here.

Comment: the following change fixed the issue: nr_15_mark = dt.replace(minute=int(nearest/60), second=nearest%60)

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this version. In principle it handle possible overflow of hours and days

```
def flat_data(dt, period, f = round):
     minut = int(dt.strftime('%M'))*60
     secon = int(dt.strftime('%S'))

     time_stamp = dt.timestamp()

     tot = minut + secon
     time_stamp -= tot 
#     print(time_stamp, tot)
     nearest = f(tot/(period*60))*(period*60)
#     print(nearest)
     flat_date= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time_stamp) + nearest)
     return flat_date
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).